# Weight-based block IO control for VMs

Tags: linux, io, kvm, block-device, cgroups

I use KVM to manage my virtual machines. I am trying to limit the resources provided for VMs. I am able to limit the CPU and memory allocated for VMs using libvirt/cgroups. Now I want to control the disk time allotted for each VM by applying some weights. I looked at blkio control from cgroups. Since VM is just a Linux process, I will be able to use cgroups but I am not sure whether it will work for asynchronous IO too. If not, can someone suggest a good alternative solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blkio in [cgroup terminology](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/ch-Subsystems_and_Tunable_Parameters.html) stands for *access to I/O on block devices*. It does not seem to be about regulating all the different ways software developers have at hand for I/O-related purposes.

It seems to be targeted mainly to I/O on ***devices***, not on the way software has access to devices. It can limit the number of iops, the bandwidth or a weight with other processes, in other things. It seems that buffered write is not supported by blockio at the moment. It's in the [official documentation](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/ch-Subsystems_and_Tunable_Parameters.html):

> Currently, the Block I/O subsystem does not work for buffered write operations. It is primarily targeted at direct I/O, although it works for buffered read operations.

If you take a look at [this presentation](http://www.redhat.com/summit/2011/presentations/summit/in_the_weeds/friday/WangKozdemba_f_1130_cgroups14.pdf) from Linda Wang and Bob Kozdemba of Red Hat, on page 20+, you'll see that the graph is about the device bandwidth per VM, not about random vs blocking vs asynchronous I/O.

It seems there has been [recent](http://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2011-November/msg00202.html) [work](http://www.digipedia.pl/usenet/thread/11773/26322/) by Red Hat to implement it directly into virsh. It has been [released](http://libvirt.org/news.html) last week in libvirt 0.9.9. In a few months, you'll be able to do something like this in your favorite distribution:

```
virsh blkiotune domA --device-weights /dev/sda,250
virsh blkiotune domB --device-weights /dev/sda,750
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use ionice, it's like nice but for IO.

Comment: Is `ionice` a better alternative than using `blkio` from cgroups? Does it provide something the OP's current solution does not? Do you know how it relates to asynchronous IO?

Comment: Caleb it will be great if you can just give a gist on what is asynchronous IO and how does it differ from synchronous IO with respect to an operating system.

Comment: @Caleb: See above.